Is Google NGram Viewer really useful?
Since I arrived here, I’ve noticed that many authoritative users make use of Google Ngram Viewer to answer questions such as this one.
I harbour some doubts about the usefulness of this tool. The corpus of Google Books in Italian is not a selected one: it includes a variety of works, ranging from literary works to academic essays, technical writings, novels, etc.
Even though it is incomparably more useful than a plain Google search, because a book is supposed to be written in a more careful way than a message board post, I question its usefulness as a tool to check the real usage of a word or phrase, since one cannot distinguish between the literary usage, the journalistic one, and so on.
I find it better to look up in such corpora as those of the online archives of the main newspapers (La Repubblica, Corriere della Sera, La Stampa) or that of bibliotecaitaliana.it (which includes many literary works from the origins to the 20th century). Of course, this is not an ideal solution either — as it’s rather a quick and easy way to answer a question in a Q&A website that has the Accademia della Crusca as the main competitor —, but lets users, especially the foreign ones, to have more specific information about the usage of a word in a certain parlance.
However, in most cases a simple dictionary of modern usage, or a modern dictionary tout court, is enough to give an exhaustive answer. Moreover, if one wanted to know, e.g., which of two variants is the most used right now, it might be better to look both of them up in Google Trends: granted, you can get lots of untrustable results, but that’s the only way to capture the living usage.
What’s your take on Google Ngram Viewer?

Da quando sono arrivato qui, ho notato che molti utenti autorevoli usano Google Ngram Viewer per rispondere alle domande, come in questo caso.
Nutro qualche dubbio sull’utilità di questo strumento. Il corpus di Google Libri in italiano non è selezionato: include infatti opere disparate, che vanno dalla letteratura alla saggistica accademica, agli scritti tecnici, i romanzi, ecc.
Benché sia incomparabilmente più utile che una semplice ricerca su Google, perché un libro, di solito, è scritto in maniera più sorvegliata rispetto a un messaggio pubblicato in uno spazio di discussione in Rete, dubito che sia utile per verificare l’uso effettivo di una parola o di una locuzione, dal momento che non è possibile fare distinzione tra l’uso letterario, l’uso giornalistico, e cosí via.
Ritengo sia meglio consultare corpora come quelli degli archivi digitali dei principali quotidiani (La Repubblica, Corriere della Sera, La Stampa) o quello di bibliotecaitaliana.it (che comprende molte opere letterarie dalle origini al ventesimo secolo). Ovviamente, nemmeno questa è una soluzione ideale — è piuttosto un rapido espediente per rispondere in un sito di domande e risposte che subisce la concorrenza dell’Accademia della Crusca —, ma permette agli utenti, specialmente se stranieri, di avere informazioni piú specifiche sull’uso di una parola in un certo linguaggio.
Peraltro, nella gran parte dei casi un semplice dizionario dell’uso, o un dizionario moderno e basta, è sufficiente per dare una risposta esaustiva. Inoltre, se si volesse sapere, per esempio, quale tra due varianti di una parola sia la piú usata ora, potrebbe essere meglio cercarle in Google Trends: certo, cosí avremmo molti risultati non affidabili, ma solo in questo modo potremmo intercettare l’uso vivo.
Voi che cosa pensate di Google Ngram Viewer?

Ho sempre pensato che i risultati di Google Ngram devono essere interpretati con molta cautela. Nell'esempio citato, cioè in http://italian.stackexchange.com/a/5432/707, i risultati di Ngram comprendono frasi come «erano stati abbandonati su due piedi in una stanza d'albergo», «Verificazioni tali, fatte così su due piedi in una conversazione, ...», «è vantaggioso operare i due piedi in una medesima seduta», frasi che non hanno niente a che vedere con la domanda.

A mio parere, non è solo una questione d’interpretazione, che pure è fondamentale quando ci possano essere ambiguità. C’è di piú: come dicevo, il corpus di Ngram Viewer è altamente eterogeneo e non selezionato, perciò si rischia, per esempio, di far passare per uso comune un uso settoriale. Non ne nego, però, l’utilità per avere un’indicazione di massima.

Anche per questa ragione i risultati di Ngram Viewer devono essere presi con molta cautela.
